# 'Extended Properties' out after open and close connection string

Tags: excel, delphi, citrix

In my application I can import Excel files but on Citrix I get an error:

```
Unrecognized database format
```

I have a default connection string:

```
const
  CXlsxConnectionString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=%s; Mode=Read; Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"';
```

In the `%s` I set the .xls or .xlsx file. Next code:

```
conExcel.Close;
conExcel.ConnectionString:= GetXlsConnectionString(excelFile);
// --> Connectionstring: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Myexcel.xlsx; Mode=Read; Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"
conExcel.Open;
conExcel.Close;
// --> Connectionstring: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Myexcel.xlsx; Mode=Read;
```

After an open and a close of the `conExcel` (TADOConnection) the Extended Properties is gone.

When I want to load the sheet like: (dstSheetData --> TADODataSet, is connected with `conExcel`)

```
  sql := format('select * from [%s]', [sheet]);
  dstSheetData.Close;
  dstSheetData.CommandText := sql;
  dstSheetData.Open;
```

I get the error because the `Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"` is gone.
This occurs on my Citrix server.

a connection with udl works when I open the udl on command
C:\Windows\syswow64\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\Ole DB\oledb32.dll" OpenDSLFile C:\myConnection.udl

It is not a connection problem. The problem is that the extended properties goes away after open and close the connection.

The same resutl if I use Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 or Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

**initialize Connectionstring:**

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\myExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes";Persist Security Info=False

**connectionstring after connection.open:**

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\myExcel.xls;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;

**Connectionstring after conection.close:**

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\myExcel.xls;Persist Security Info=False;

**Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes" is gone**

Someone, any suggestion?

Ok, I found a solution.
I've change the CXlsxConnectionString

```
const
      CXlsxConnectionString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=%s;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don''t Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;';
```

Comment: Try to create a UDL file (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e(v=vs.71).aspx) with a hard coedet link and test it

Comment: @MartynA: The problem is that the Extended properties is gone after connection.close on Citrix.

Comment: Yes, I follow your problem.  Do you get the same result if you move the .Xls file to its own new folder?  Istr that Ado access to an Excel workbook could be problematic if it didn't have its own folder.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I use the result of the connectionstring when the connection is open.